# Correr script de Python desde vb.net pasando varialbes de VB como parametros de Python

Tags: python, vb.net

Estoy tratando de correr un script de python al precionar un botón en visual basic. Necesito pasar variables de visual basic a python.

intente lo siguiente:

```
Shell("path\programa.py arg1 arg2")
```

Pero al hacerlo me sale el error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Archivo no encontrado.'

también intente:

```
cd path & python progama.py
```

Este comando funciona desde la consola de windows pero no desde visual basic

Answer (score 2):

Para ejecutar un programa en python debes llamar primero al ejecutable de python y pasarle como argumento el programa que quieres correr, asi que en tu caso sería algo asi:

```
Shell("python path\programa.py arg1 arg2")
```

Para que esto funcione, el ejecutable del python debe estar en la variable de entorno `PATH` para que el sistema pueda encontrarlo.

De todas maneras,en lugar de `Shell` yo te recomendaría usar `Process` que es mas potente y flexible. En tu caso, sería algo asi:

```
Dim ejecutable As String = "pyton.exe" //aqui puedes poner la ruta a python.exe si no está 
                                       //en la variable de entorno PATH
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(ejecutable) 
psi.WorkingDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path) //Cambias el directorio activo a tu path
psi.Arguments ="programa.py arg1 arg2"

Process.Start(psi)
```